# Uploading photos to Google Drive folder via Google Apps Script form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload files to a Google Drive folder with dynamically created subfolders. The subfolders are created from the 'name' and 'email' inputted in the form along with the files to be uploaded. However, rather than just making one folder for one set of data, when the form is submitted it is creating multiple folders (inconsistently) - sometimes one per photo, sometimes all photos in one folder. There is no repeatable process that produces one result or the other. It seems to be completely random and unpredictable.

Everything I have looked at has shown me the same server-side code. Or very similar code which I have also tested. I'm now completely stuck and have turned here as a last resort.

form.html (above  not included)

```
<form id="form" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;background-color: #fff;padding: 40px;border-radius: 20px;">
          <table style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label for="name" style="color: #1a2b56;">Full Name*</label>    
                <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <label for="email" style="color: #1a2b56;">Email Address*</label>
                <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="upload-btn-wrapper" style="width: 50%;text-align: left;">
                    <button class="button">Browse</button>
                    <input id="files" type="file" multiple required>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="files-chosen" placeholder="Select pictures to upload*" style="padding: 15px 0;margin: 0;text-align: left;width: 100%" disabled>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <div style="padding: 20px;">
                    <button class="button" type="submit" onclick="submitForm();  return false;">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>        
                <p style="color: red;text-align: left;padding: 15px">* = required</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <p id="progress"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>

<script>
    var a;
    window.fileList = [];
    var filenames = "";
    var input = document.getElementById('files');
    var infoArea = document.getElementById('files-chosen');

    input.addEventListener('change',showFileName);
        
    function showFileName(event) {
        var filenames = "";
        window.fileList = [];
        var input = event.srcElement;

        if (input.files.length == 0){
            alert("Please choose a picture/pictures to upload")
            return false;
        }else{
            for (a=0; a < input.files.length; a++){
                var fileName = input.files[a].name;
                if (input.files.length == 1){
                    filenames+=fileName;
                }else{
                    filenames+=fileName+", ";
                }
                window.fileList.push(input.files[a]);
            }
            document.getElementById('files-chosen').value=filenames;
        }
    }

    function submitForm(){
        window.complete = 0;
        alert("Please wait, this may take a while, do not close the page - click OK")
                //alert(window.fileList.length);
                document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = window.complete+"/"+window.fileList.length+" uploaded";
        window.fileList.forEach(function(file){
            sendFile(file);
        });
    }

    sendFile = function(file){
        var fullName = document.getElementById('name').value;
        var emailAdd = document.getElementById('email').value;
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(e) {
            google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(successShow)
            .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result, file.name, fullName, emailAdd);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function successShow(e){
        if (e === "OK"){
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "";
            window.complete++;
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = window.complete+"/"+window.fileList.length+" uploaded";
        }
        if (window.complete == window.fileList.length){
            alert("Pictures uploaded successfully");
            document.getElementById("form").reset();
            document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }

    function reset() {
        document.getElementById("form").reset();
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML = "";
    }
</script>
```

**server.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms.html').setTitle("Upload Files");
}

function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email) {
  try {
    const folderName = "Wedding Pictures";
    const folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);
    const folder = folders.hasNext() ? folders.next() : DriveApp.createFolder(folderName);
    
    const subfolderName = [name, email].join(" - ");
    const subfolder = folder.getFoldersByName(subfolderName);
    const subfolder = subfolders.hasNext() ? subfolders.next() : folder.createFolder(subfolderName);

    const contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';'));
    const bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7));
    const blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file);
    
    const createdFile = subfolder.createFile(blob);
    
    return "OK";
    
  } catch (error) {
    return error.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: "However, rather than just making one folder for one set of data, when the form is submitted it is creating multiple folders (inconsistently) - sometimes one per photo, sometimes all photos in one folder." You need to provide us with details of when the script is working as expected, and when it is causing problems as described. The issues could relate to the "name" and "email" in your form that we cannot reproduce. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: First, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. If `However, rather than just making one folder for one set of data, when the form is submitted it is creating multiple folders (inconsistently) - sometimes one per photo, sometimes all photos in one folder.` is your current issue, I guessed that the reason for your current issue is due to that the methods of the asynchronous process are used in a loop. So, in your situation, how about summarizing multiple files and sending them to Google Apps Script side?